# how to route always to www.mydomain.com/ cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I want to clear everything from my url and just leave www.mydomain.com/... no profiles no controller no action no ids no vars in the url...

is that posible?

Comment: its possible, but not reliable.

Comment: You mean, even when navigating to any page within your site, the URL will only show "mydomain.com"? a) Why?! b) It sure is possible with ugly hacks, but it actually works against the user. So again, Why?!

Comment: It can be done with htaccess, but don't.

Answer (score -1):

Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'something', 'action' => 'here', 123, 'some' => 'named_params'));

nothing wrong with doing that. its not a hack, and its 100% reliable. and no, you dont need to do it with htaccess